# Прочитать структуры из вектора

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Есть вектор структур:

```
std::vector<SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION> spi(...);
```

Через `ZwQuerySystemInformation` я получила все эти структуры, но вот затык: не знаю как прочитать данные структур из вектора. Понимаю так, что нужно брать поле `NextEntryOffset` из `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` и складывать его с адресом первой структуры, но как обойти все структуры?
Про `CreateToolhelpSnapshot32` знаю, но использовать не хочу, так как там все гораздо проще.